# Set all blog posts to a new category

Tags: wordpress, categories, posts

I need to set all my blog posts to a new Category. I can't do that just selecting posts page by page and applying because my post DB is really huge.

Do you know a plugin or how to do that in an SQL query or any solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-move/

> Bulk Move is a WordPress Plugin which can be used to move posts in
>   bulk from one category or tag to another. This Plugin can also be used
>   to remove posts from a certain category or tag.

It's safer than a SQL query. Backup your database before using.

Comment: Thanks but I don't exactly need this. I need to ADD a global category. Not move... I have created Blog Category and I want, for example, to all Apple, Linux, Windows Category posts add the Blog one. This plugin is cool but just gives me the option of move.